# Assign value to deleted object

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a small homework problem.
The following code is given:

```
int * p;
p = new int;
*p = 5;
```

The question is: Why is it useless to do

```
p = 0;
delete p;
```

but usefull to do

```
delete p;
p = 0;
```

?

In my opinion, both is useless. If an object is deleted, no new value can be assigned.
I also get in both cases a `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: If `delete p; p=0;` gives you a segfault, you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: I try to return the value of `p` afterwards.

Comment: Teaching such as this is why C++ has such a bad reputation as a hard to use language with memory leaks/corruption. With C++11 now, you should never write delete in your code*. With the addition of make_unique in the C++14, you should never write new in your code*. (* = unless you are an expert writing writing low-level components)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Why it is useful for the following:

```
delete p;
p = 0;
```

Quoting from stroustrup's answer: [Why doesn't delete zero out its operand?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#delete-zero)

> Consider
>
> ```
> delete p;
> // ...
> delete p;
> ```
>
> If the ... part doesn't touch p then the second "delete p;" is a serious error that a C++ implementation cannot effectively protect itself against (without unusual precautions). **Since deleting a zero pointer is harmless by definition, a simple solution would be for "delete p;" to do a "p=0;" after it has done whatever else is required.However, C++ doesn't guarantee that.**
>   One reason is that the operand of delete need not be an lvalue. Consider:
>
> ```
> delete p+1;
> delete f(x);
> ```
>
> Here, the implementation of delete does not have a pointer to which it can assign zero. These examples may be rare, but they do imply that it is not possible to guarantee that `any pointer to a deleted object is 0.'' A simpler way of bypassing that`rule'' is to have two pointers to an object:
>
> ```
> T* p = new T;
> T* q = p;
> delete p;
> delete q;   // ouch!
> ```
>
> **C++ explicitly allows an implementation of delete to zero out an lvalue operand, and I had hoped that implementations would do that, but that idea doesn't seem to have become popular with implementers.**
>   If you consider zeroing out pointers important, consider using a destroy function:

```
template<class T> inline void destroy(T*& p) { delete p; p = 0; }
```

> Consider this yet-another reason to minimize explicit use of new and delete by relying on standard library containers, handles, etc.
>
> Note that passing the pointer as a reference (to allow the pointer to be zero'd out) has the added benefit of preventing destroy() from being called for an rvalue:
>
> ```
> int* f();
> int* p;
> // ...
> destroy(f());   // error: trying to pass an rvalue by non-const reference
> destroy(p+1);   // error: trying to pass an rvalue by non-const reference
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Recall that deleting `0` is allowed. Therefore, when you do this

```
p = 0;
delete p; // Deleting zero is ignored
```

you throw away the old value of `p` (thus creating a memory leak), and then call `delete 0`, which is ignored.

When you do this, however

```
delete p;
p = 0;
```

you use the old value first (to de-allocate the `int`), and only then zero it out. This makes sense, because the old value of `p` becomes both useless and dangerous as soon as `delete` is executed.

Comment: While a C++ compiler will ignore a zero valued pointer when you try to delete it, ie will compile without error. However, this will cause a seg fault for sure at runtime.

Comment: @Ozraptor Not according to a standard: both `delete 0` and `free(NULL)` are allowed. Here is a running sample: [link](http://ideone.com/1PNXrt).

Comment: @Ozraptor: This is explicitly allowed by the standard: section 5.3.5 paragraph 2

Comment: @dasblinkenlight and Vaughn Cato: I will have to try this then. Has this always been the case or is it a C++11 change? I'm sure that "delete (0)" used to cause a seg fault, as was seen by the original poster above?

Comment: @Ozraptor As far as I know, this has always been like that (I suspect it has been modeled after the behavior of `free` in C). As far as OP's segfault goes, I think it's from something unrelated, such as not returning `0` from `main` or something equivally simple.

Answer (score 0):

This sets the pointer to null and then calls delete:

```
p = 0;
delete p;
```

It is like saying

```
delete 0;
```

I think what you are thinking is that it is setting the int that p points to to zero, but that would be done like this:

```
*p = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are assigning the value of the POINTER p to be '0', not the value of the int that p points to. That's why it is both useless (will in fact cause a memory leak), and causes a seg fault when you try to delete from memory address '0'. EDIT - actually I just learned that the segfault is not caused by the 'delete 0', which is ignored according to the standard, so something else is causing that.

In the second case you are freeing the memory / object pointed to by p (which should be fine), and then assigning the pointer to have a value '0', which should also be Ok, so not sure why you are seg faulting there? In terms of usefulness, it used to be considered good practice to set free'd pointers to a null or '0' value so you can test for that before de-referencing them.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = NULL;
```

and

```
p = 0;
```

In the above case you are assigning value to the pointer and not to the object it points to.

Are one and the same. delete function is used to free the memory allocated dynamically to an object.

1. When you say

   ```
   delete p;
   p = 0;
   ```

   It is like saying free the memory allocated to the pointer p and
   then you are saying assign the pointer to NULL. Which is right.
2. In the other case when you do this

   ```
   p = 0;
   delete p;
   ```

   You are saying assign the pointer to NULL first. Now the pointer p
   is not pointing to any valid dynamically assigned memory. So later
   when you say delete p the compiler cannot find any memory to free
   and hence throws a segmentation fault.